# If Watch app opened before HealthKit accepted, show alert

Tags: watchkit

Was wondering what the best practice for this is.

If an app that used `HealthKit` is downloaded, and then the Watch app is started before the iPhone app, `HealthKit` will not have been allowed yet.

In that instance, the user is going to think the Watch app is broken because no totals or data will be updated, etc.

Is there a best way to avoid this or at least alert the user that you have done or seen?

I'm assuming I'd set some sort of `bool` that is set to false, and maybe put an alert up on the first screen of the Watch app until `HealthKit` has been allowed.

Comment: How are you downloading the watch app without the iPhone app?

Comment: @AshleyMills You're not.  Once the app is downloaded, the first app that is opened is the Watch app (instead of the iPhone app where all of the the HealthKit permissions are asked of the user).  In which case you're using the Watch app without having accepted any of the permissions, and the Watch app doesn't have those capabilities, and the user wouldn't be sure why.

Comment: Ah, I've updated your question slightly.

Comment: @AshleyMills ah ok perfect.  Any ideas on an answer too potentially?

Comment: I'm working on the same problem now. I have need to have app onboarding _and_ healthkit auth complete first. If I come up with an answer I'll let you know

Comment: @AshleyMills fun problem ha.  I'll let you know if I figure something out too.